# How to read a variable found in the middle of a file

Tags: c, file

So my file has this content:

```
Name: Bob Charles
Address: 10 strawberry avenue, port
Age: 19
Tel num: 2383234
Balance: $100.00
```

I want to read the balance and store it in a float variable. If I use fseek it will only work for this specific person, as another person may have a different address, balance etc. I've tried to following as a second option:

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen(query, "r");
fscanf(fp, "\n\n\n\n Balance: $%f", &newBal);    
fclose(fp);
printf("bal: %d", newBal);
```

This prints newBal as 0

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Never use a float for a dollar amount.

Comment: Yet another `strtok` question.

Comment: with printf you use `%f` to print out a float, not `%d`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `fgets` to read a file line by line.

```
ssize_t read = -1;

size_t len = 0;

FILE * file = NULL;

file = fopen("file.txt", "r");

if (file == NULL)
{
    // handle error
}

char line[256];

size_t line_sz = sizeof(line) - 1;

while (fgets(line, line_sz, file) != NULL)
{
    char *key = NULL;

    char *value = NULL;

    sscanf(line, "%s:%s", &key, &value);

    // handle key and value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best strategy for dealing with such files is:

1. Read a line of text.
2. Decide how to interpret the contents of the line.
3. Repeat until there are no more lines.

---

```
// Make it as large as you need
#define LINE_SIZE 200

char line[LINE_SIZE];
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen(query, "r");
if ( fp == NULL )
{
   // Deal with error
   exit(1);
}

while ( fgets(line, LINE_SIZE, fp) != NULL )
{
    processLine(line);
}

fclose(fp);
```

where `processLine` can be defined as:

```
void processLine(char* line)
{
    char const* nameToken = "Name:";
    char const* addressToken = "Address:";
    char const* ageToken = "Age:";
    char const* telNumToken = "Tel num:";
    char const* balanceToken = "Balance:";

    if ( startsWith(line, nameToken) )
    {
        // Deal with name
    }

    else if ( startsWith(line, addressToken) )
    {
        // Deal with address
    }

    else if ( startsWith(line, ageToken) )
    {
        // Deal with age
    }

    else if ( startsWith(line, telNumToken) )
    {
        // Deal with tel number
    }

    else if ( startsWith(line, balanceToken) )
    {
        // Deal with balance
    }
}
```

and  `startsWith` can be defined as:

```
bool startsWith(char* line, char const* token)
{
   return (strncmp(line, token, strlen(token)) == 0);
}
```

Comment: @JustinRickman, if you need to extract the name and store in some variable or an element of an array, you will have to write code to take care of that. You may have to pass some arguments to `processLine` in order to do that. You can also leave that block empty and ignore the line.